# Possibly incorrect Matlab error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch"

Tags: matlab

Matlab is giving me the error, "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" however I don't think there should be an issue. The code is below but basically I have a temp matrix that mimics the dimensions of another matrix, testData (actually a subset of it). I can assign the output of imread to the temp matrix but not to a subset of testData that has the same dimensions. I can even use the size function to prove they are the same dimensions yet one works and one doesn't. So I set temp = imread and then testData = temp and it works. But why should I have to do that?

```
fileNames = dir('Testing\*.pgm');
numFiles = size(fileNames, 1);
testData = zeros(32257, numFiles);
temp = zeros(32256, 1);

for i = 1 : numFiles,
  fileName = fileNames(i).name;

  % Extracts some info from the file's name and stores it in the first row
  testData(1, i) = str2double(fileName(6:7));

  % Here temp has the same dimensions as testData(2:end, i)
  % yet testData(2:end, i) = imread(fileName) doesn't work
  % however it works if I use temp as a "middleman" variable
  temp(:) = imread(fileName);
  testData(2:end, i) = temp(:);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file that you're reading is a color image, `imread` returns an `MxNx3` array. You can't assign a `3D` array to a `1D` vector without reshaping it, even if it contains the same number of elements. That's probably why you get the error when you try to assign the output of `imread` directly to `testData`. However, when you use an intermediate variable and collapse it into a column vector, the assignment works because now you're assigning a `1D` vector to another `1D` vector of equal size.

If you don't want to use an additional step, try this

```
testData(2:end,i)=reshape(imread(fileName),32256,1);
```

Comment: It's actually grayscale, but the reshape thing works fine. Thanks.